# Is there a way to have Eclipse separate imports by domain?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I know that Eclipse lets you add a blank line between com.* and net.* imports, for example. Is it possible to add a blank line between groups of domains? Something like:

```
import com.somedomain.p;
import com.somedomain.p2;

import com.somedomain2.p;
import com.somedomain2.p2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, you can go to *Preferences* > *Organize Imports*, and then add new import groups.

Use your case for example, you may add

> com.somedomain
>
> com.somedomain2

And then eclipse will group them into difference groups with a blank line in between.

Comment: Right, but I would have to do this for every particular domain. Is there some generic pattern that I can use to denote this?

Comment: @Phillip There is no generic pattern, you have to add an explicit entry for each package